# AudioBufferSourceNode.buffer deprecated?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

According to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/buffer

AudioBufferSourceNode.buffer is now deprecated. What is the new alternative? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: By looking at the various bug descriptions about this topic, it seems that that MDN statement 'deprecated' is misleading : what's deprecated is the ability to set it several times. So one should just set it once on a new AudioBufferSourceNode, for each and every new play of a BufferSource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is just mislabeled on the MDN. To the best of my knowledge, `AudioBufferSourceNode.buffer` has not been deprecated. The most recent version of the W3C draft still has it in there.

There has been some talk (https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/288) of deprecating the ability to *reassign* the value of `buffer` once it's been set. So maybe the person who marked `buffer` as deprecated was referring to that.

Comment: Cool- still has the "thumbs down" deprecated notice in the nav on the left though!

Comment: Should be fixed now if you hard reload. The article still had a "Deprecated" tag, which I removed.

Comment: It still says "[1] Removed in Chrome version 44.0. Was supported with a webkit prefix from version 14." here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/buffer and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode along with thumb down.